# letras negras en ireport y netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport

Cuando genero el preview de mi reporte, las letras salen como deseo: pintadas con negrita:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero Luego cuando lo guardo como .pdf, me genera de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque pasa esto? Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione :D  debido a que imprimirlo con adobe pdf, me salia diferente a como queria que salga. PERO, utilizando la impresion por defecto , si funciona!